# Podfile - specify sub dependency version

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Is there a way to force a sub dependency version for a Pod dependency? I have this Pod dependency;

```
Podfile
...
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

It has a subdependncy on boost-for-react-native without specifying a version which results in 1.57.0 being installed.

```
Podfile.lock
...
  - Folly (2016.09.26.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
```

I need version 1.63.0. If I specify that in the parent Podfile I still end up with 1.57.0.

```
Podfile
...
```

pod 'boost-for-react-native', '~> 1.63.0'

I believe I need to specify it on the Folly file itself.

Comment: it should work if you specify `boost-for-react-native` version in Podfile. Cocoapods should use first one defined.

Comment: I would have thought so too and yet I get 1.57.0 in my Pods folder every time.